# Deflated wheel on new Rav4?

Tags: toyota, tires, wheels, rav4, tire-pressure

I got my new 2021 Rav4 less than a month ago and only put about 110 miles on it but yesterday I noticed one of the rear wheels is significantly deflated(and almost flat). I only remember a glass bottle cracking in a parking lot but that was 4-5 days ago and didn't really think much about it at the time. I'm new to cars so not sure what I should do at this point. Would I have to buy a completely new tire or is there a way to fix it? Would a portable pump like [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07VMM69N9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VMM69N9)
fix the issue? Or do I take the car to the dealership and would they fix it for free under the 2-year Toyota Care warranty or should I go to a tire shop down the street(I'm in Queens, NYC)? Honestly, I didn't expect to run into trouble this early in my new car and would greatly appreciate advice from experienced drivers/mechanics.

Comment: IFAIK the 2-year Toyota care is a service plan. The warranty probably excludes tyre damage, but it is possible that there is insurance on them. Ask the dealer, but if you have to pay for a repair (or another tyre) it is usually cheaper to visit a tyre shop. New cars are not immune from punctures. I do carry a portable pump.

Comment: ... but only to get me to a safe place or to a shop when there is a slow leakage.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If you need to get a tire replacement, you might have to replace both rear tires. Typical advice says to replace tires in pairs, as in both tires on the same axle. However, with as few miles as you have on that set of tires, you might be able to get away with just the one tire. But don't be surprised if the mechanic tries to sell you 2 tires, even though "you need only one".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where the damage to the tire is at whether you'd need to replace the tire. If it is on the side wall, tire places will not fix it. I'd assume (from your description) the damage is most likely in the tread area. You won't know until you get it looked at, though. Tread can most likely be fixed with a patch from the back side, unless the damage is great. Considering it seems like a slow leak, it should be okay to fix.

As far as a pump goes, it's just a stop gap measure. It's not going to fix/solve anything. You'll need to get the tire fixed long term.

It appears the Toyota Care warranty only covers changing out a flat tire for the spare. It doesn't cover road hazards, which if the glass is what has caused your troubles, is what it would be considered.

Any competent tire shop should be able to figure out what's going on with the tire as well as what the solution is going to be to get the car back to golden. If you don't like what they have to say or what they are doing, you can always go to another place and get a 2nd opinion. Just ask them their opinion and their solution and go from there. I never suggest going to the dealership because they usually price gouge on anything they do.

Comment: **ANY** mechanic can price gouge - not only or exclusively dealers...

Comment: @SolarMike - You are right. It's just that stealerships have a propensity for doing it **ALL THE TIME**.